# combobox text align right to left?

Tags: vb.net

i have this code to change combobox fill colour,every thing work perfect 
but what i need to make the combobox text align right to left , any help pleas.

this is my code :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DrawItem
If e.Index < 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim rect As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    If e.State And DrawItemState.Selected Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightSeaGreen, rect) 'change the selected color you like
    Else
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, rect)
    End If
    Dim colorname As String = ComboBox1.Items(e.Index)
    Dim ba As New SolidBrush(Color.FromName(colorname))
    Dim b2 As Brush = Brushes.Black 'add one
    e.Graphics.DrawString(colorname, Me.ComboBox1.Font, b2, rect.X, rect.Y)
End Sub

Private Sub combo_colors1()
    Me.ComboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
    Me.ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    Me.ComboBox1.BeginUpdate()
    ComboBox1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Formatting flags of the TextRenderer.DrawText method:

```
'e.Graphics.DrawString(colorname, Me.ComboBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, rect.X, rect.Y)
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, colorname, Me.ComboBox1.Font, e.Bounds, _
                      Color.Black, Color.Empty, _
                      TextFormatFlags.Right Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
```